# Has there been any success in using deep learning for reverse engineering?

Tags: memory, patch-reversing, software-security

So has there been any success in using deep learning for doing reverse engineering?

i couldn't find anything useful other than some theoretical papers, so was there any talk about this in recent security conferences, or actual success of doing so?

Comment: Interesting topic. What do you want exactly to reach with deep learning? The disassembly process? Or classification of malware? Recognize obfuscation?

Comment: Are you focused just on deep learning specifically or machine learning methods in RE in general?

Comment: @pudi yes, building a "program" with the help of   deep learning that can disassemble any given program with a high accuracy rate, has there been any success in this field?

Comment: @SYS_V deep learning would be preferable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can AI be used to write better decompilers/disassemblers?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18866/can-ai-be-used-to-write-better-decompilers-disassemblers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about deep learning, but if you are looking for general results on using machine learning for reverse engineering, there was a paper called "Evolving Exact Decompilation" published at the Workshop on Binary Analysis Research 2018, where the researchers claimed to have learned/evolved the ability to decompile a C program. See [the paper here](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~eschulte/data/bed.pdf).